# Robots.txt Specific Exclusion

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Currently my `robots.txt` is the following

```
#Sitemaps
Sitemap: http://www.baopals.com.com/sitemap.xml

#Disallow select URLs
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /products/
```

My products have a lot of duplicate content as I pull over data from taobao.com and automatically translate it resulting in a lot of duplicate and low quality names which is why I just disallow the whole thing. However I manually change the titles on certain products and re-save them to the database and showcase them on the homepage with proper translations they just still get saved back to `/products/` and are lost forever when I remove them from the homepage.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to allow the products that I save to the homepage with the updated translations still be indexed by google or am I forced to change the directory of the manually updated products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde I disagree, I'm wondering programmatically if its possible to index these products without changing my file structure. The seo tag seems to be relevant

Answer (score 0):

Some bots (including the Googlebot) support the `Allow` field. This allows you to specify paths that should be allowed to crawl anyway.

So you would have to add an `Allow` line for each product that you want to get crawled.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /products/
Allow: /products/foo-bar-1
Allow: /products/foo-foo-2
Allow: /products/bar-foo
```

But instead of disallowing *crawling* of your product pages, you might want to disallow *indexing*. Then a bot is still allowed to visit your pages and follow links, but it won’t add the pages to its search index.

Add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to each product page (in the `head`), and remove it (or change it to `index`) for each product page you want to get indexed. There’s also a corresponding HTTP header, if that’s easier for you.